# Meteor mail drops attachment

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, attachment

I am trying to send a very basic email attachment. I have been receiving email when the call is executed, but my attachment is always dropped. The recipient email is Gmail currently. I don't know if my code is incorrect or if my syntax is incorrect but I receive all but my attachment. I looked up mail-composer documentation and I seem to be conforming to those standards. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the server code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text,attachments) {
        check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);
        this.unblock();

        Email.send({
            to: to,
            from: from,
            subject: subject,
            text: text,
            attachments :[
              {   // encoded string as an attachment
                  filename: 'text1.txt',
                  contents: 'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQh',
                  encoding: 'base64'
              },
            ]
        });


    }//End SendMail funct.
});//End Method
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs the solution to this. Meteor Mail uses mailcomposer 0.15.x and does not provide encoding or any other type of attachment type besides what appears to be making a filePath to the file. I could not even get that to work, but it may. Either way encoding or dataURI's cannot be done apparently.

You can import mailcomposer 3.9.0 as an npm package and build a compliant email but you still wont be able to send it without using a totally different transfer protocol than the regular Mail.send method.